# Laravel 5.1 and 5.3 which is best for beginner

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I am new to laravel and but know core PHP well. And I am decided to create a project in laravel. So I started studying laravel. while I research about laravel, [laravel community](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/laravel/info)  says that laravel 5.1 has **Long term support(LTS)**. Now I confused which version want to use. Give me suggestions about which one want to use.

Comment: I would suggest to use the most recent version, the 5.3 because it has new features that you might want to use. And by the time you finally master Laravel, the 5.3 version will be stable enough, for sure... But it's entirely up to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gowtham I reccommend to go for 5.3 version. because of realy specious features like

**[Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scout)**: is a driver based full-text search for Eloquent

**[Laravel Mailable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail)** :is a new Mail class for sending emails in an expressive way.

**[Laravel Notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications)** : awesome feature which allows you to make quick updates through services like Slack, SMS, or Email.

**[Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport)** : Another superb feature . It is an optional package that is a full oAuth 2 server ready to go.

There are lot more which will curious you to go for 5.3 version.

Comment: I do agree with @Manish, the big down side though is that the last LTS version is 5.1. Here is a personal decision but if you willing to implement what you know in a production environment and be sure that if something comes up it will be fixed youll have to stick to 5.1

Comment: I do agree with @Manish , but laravel 5.3 released just a month ago. So It might have some bug. I am planning to do a big project using laravel. If I used laravel 5.3, would I get needed support such as bug fixes and error? and if there is a bug will it affect my project too?